# Does Talmudic-Era Hebrew or Aramaic Distinguish Between Teaching and Learning?

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, hebrew, mishna, aramaic

In English, *teaching* and *learning* are two distinct verbs, but this is not the case with (many) other languages, where the *same* word is used to express *both* concepts. Whilst pondering upon the traditional (rabbinic) Jewish practice of [excluding women from *learning* or studying the Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_in_Judaism#Views_on_the_education_of_women), I started wondering whether this might also have been the case with [Talmudic Hebrew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishnaic_Hebrew) and [Aramaic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aramaic#Post-Achaemenid_Aramaic). If there is a difference between the [Mishna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishnah) and the [Gemara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemara) with respect to usage, I would be interested in that aspect as well.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.17a.7?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=he

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both Mishnaic Hebrew and Talmudic Aramaic, the words meaning learning and teaching have the same [triliteral root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semitic_root), but they have different [*binyanim*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Hebrew_verbs#Stems).

In Hebrew, the root is ל-מ-ד. When in the *pa'al* form (*lilmod*) it means 'to learn', as opposed to the *pi'el* form (*le-lammed*) where it means 'to teach'.

A nice example of the two forms juxtaposed can be seen in [Mishnah Avot 2:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pirkei_Avot.2.5?lang=bi):

> וְלֹא הַבַּיְשָׁן לָמֵד, וְלֹא הַקַּפְּדָן מְלַמֵּד
>
> Neither can the bashful learn, nor can the impatient teach

(Parenthetically, a crucial source in the context of discouraging women from studying Torah is [Mishnah Sotah 3:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Sotah.3.4?lang=bi), which indeed talks about teaching one's daughter, not (explicitly) about a woman learning *per se*.)

(A second parenthetical remark: there is also a different verb, *lehorot*, which has more of a specific connotation of 'instructing', rather than teaching in general.)

The same holds true in Talmudic Aramaic. The root is י-ל-ף. *Lelef* means to learn, but *le-yallef* means to teach. (See e.g. [Jastrow's dictionary](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jastrow%2C_%D7%99%D6%B0%D7%9C%D6%B5%D7%99%D7%A3?lang=he).)

Comment: Were these subtle orthographical differences already effectively in place in the 200-500 CE period, or did they only come into being at a later time ?

Comment: These forms appear in Biblical Hebrew, long before 200CE

Comment: These rules apply for all triliteral verb roots, which can be transitive or intransitive depending on conjugation. So DO and DONE share the root עשה, kill and be killed share the root רצח, SAY and SAID share the root אמר, etc. etc.

Comment: @N.T. those are active vs passive. Learn and teach are both transitive. You're right generally that in most semetic languages all roots are conjugated using various 'binyanim'